Salesforce Marketing Cloud API SOAP Function Perform Automation - Login Failed error / SFMC - S3 Trigger Automation
I need to import the file from Amazon S3 bucket into Data Extension using Trigger Automation
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_define_a_file_trigger_automation.htm&type=5
For step 2 'listen for File Upload' while QA I am trying to use SOAP API function POST Perform Automation in Postman instead of building real Lambda Amazon function
Step 1
I got token via REST POST Request SFMC Token S3:
{
"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQiLCJ2ZXIiOiIxIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iOiJYZU5nV3VBN1d3MzNZREhXRFM3Qkc2MnAiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJpdzJjOGY5bGQ2cnRmOTc2c3kzYjJzNTIiLCJlaWQiOjEwMDAxMzg0Nywic3RhY2tfa2V5IjoiUzUwIiwicGxhdGZvcm1fdmVyc2lvbiI6MiwiY2xpZW50X3R5cGUiOiJTZXJ2ZXJUb1NlcnZlciIsInBpZCI6Njd9.KfDDe9SKf6MSgPYhLHXx56qeauo45cmKByvgt0yW4ys.uSE2d95bXPDHGShEEsTq4bVj1E9hsUaCubrv0VhrcwubHrU7vH2sJtsUSuAINQY5KoGNtMxvOAjas74ja4uXXKYdqfMPriU4tq5zTGZmeoSztqbW3b4-LOWsYQi_iLpQfO4664wTKXtcVf4e_Oyhczk5b7XkwX7n3n0OY00",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 1080,
"scope": "offline automations_execute automations_read automations_write",
"soap_instance_url": "https://mc-gkd31nkc0wzj1hn5b8k0fpww4.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/",
"rest_instance_url": "https://mc-gkd31nkc0wzj1hn5b8k0fpww4.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/"

}
Step 2
I used this js in Cloud Page to get Automation Object ID:Extracting ObjectID of an Automation
My Object ID = dd7e4a7c-61bc-45ea-8f9c-5ab45895755d
Step 3
SOAP Post Perform Automation function:
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Perform</a:Action>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://mc-gkd31nkc0wzj1hn5b8k0fpww4.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
    <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQiLCJ2ZXIiOiIxIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iOiJYZU5nV3VBN1d3MzNZREhXRFM3Qkc2MnAiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJpdzJjOGY5bGQ2cnRmOTc2c3kzYjJzNTIiLCJlaWQiOjEwMDAxMzg0Nywic3RhY2tfa2V5IjoiUzUwIiwicGxhdGZvcm1fdmVyc2lvbiI6MiwiY2xpZW50X3R5cGUiOiJTZXJ2ZXJUb1NlcnZlciIsInBpZCI6Njd9.KfDDe9SKf6MSgPYhLHXx56qeauo45cmKByvgt0yW4ys.uSE2d95bXPDHGShEEsTq4bVj1E9hsUaCubrv0VhrcwubHrU7vH2sJtsUSuAINQY5KoGNtMxvOAjas74ja4uXXKYdqfMPriU4tq5zTGZmeoSztqbW3b4-LOWsYQi_iLpQfO4664wTKXtcVf4e_Oyhczk5b7XkwX7n3n0OY00"</fueloauth>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
        <Action>start</Action>
        <Definitions>
            <Definition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Automation">
                <ObjectID>dd7e4a7c-61bc-45ea-8f9c-5ab45895755d</ObjectID>
            </Definition>
        </Definitions>
    </PerformRequestMsg>
</s:Body>

</s:Envelope>
However my response is "Login Failed":
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:6bb2a9c3-89d8-4592-931e-df69aea7059b</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:63e388a8-d12b-404f-893c-1ae10ab3373b</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-fe680fe3-92df-4502-977f-43bc2a889688">
            <wsu:Created>2024-04-08T14:19:32Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2024-04-08T14:24:32Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
</env:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
        <soap:Code>
            <soap:Value xmlns:q0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">q0:Security</soap:Value>
        </soap:Code>
        <soap:Reason>
            <soap:Text xml:lang="en">Login Failed</soap:Text>
        </soap:Reason>
        <soap:Node>https://mc-gkd31nkc0wzj1hn5b8k0fpww4.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</soap:Node>
    </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

My S3 File Location is validated
My Installed Package has Automation Component with Read, Write, Execute Access
My Automation with Trigger Automation Entry and Import Activity is activated
I was trying to updated 1st Step and insert the most updated token - the result is the same
Any ideas why the response is Login failed?
